# Why can't I call del [:] on a dict?

Tags: python, dictionary, datamodel

What's going on here?

```
>>> a = {1: "a", 2: "b"}
>>> del a[1]
>>> a
{2: 'b'}
>>> a = {1: "a", 2: "b"}
>>> del a[:]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type
>>> a.clear()
>>> a
{}
```

Why must I call [`dict.clear`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.clear)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a[:]` is a special case of a slicing operation, which is defined only for sequences. It is a short form of `a[0:len(a)]`. A dict is not a sequence.

Comment: Can you link to documentation specifying that `[:]` is equivalent to `[0:len(a)]`?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange note (4)

Answer (score 3):

`a[:]` is a quick way to make a shallow copy of a `list` (and `tuple`). See towards the bottom of the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html) for clarification on different types of copying.

Thus, it would reason to say that del a[:] on a dictionary doesn't really make much sense.

If you want to delete the entire dictionary, you can simply do `del a`

```
>>> a = {1: "a", 2: "b"}
>>> del a
>>> a

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
    a
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
>>>
```

Comment: Wrong. `del S[:]` on a sequence deletes all the items but does not touch the name itself, as opposed to `del S` which only deletes the name and does not affect the items.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: I'm confused as to why that statement behaves that way. Since s[:] would return a shallow copy of the list, it seems logical that del s[:] would merely delete the returned object, but it doesnt' work that way. Any idea why? Is it just some weird quirk of the language?

Comment: @Joel: Yes. `del` is special-cased when the name is being indexed, and the `__delitem__()` method of the object is invoked instead.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is rather simple: It isn't defined. There's no reason why it couldn't work, if someone put the effort into catching the empty slice and delegating to the appropriate method.

On the other hand, this would violate a symmetry principle with assigning and getting the same slice, so probably would not gain acceptance.

Comment: Can you link to the required special method names that would allow this? (I have no intention of doing it, but would it's relevant as to why this call fails).

Comment: The three methods at http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__ .

Answer (score 1):

If this functionality is crucial to your system, you could subclass the dict builtin to add this function.

```
import sys
class newdict(dict):

    def __delslice__(self,i,j):
        if i==0 and j==sys.maxint:
            self.clear()
        else:
            dict.__delslice__(self,i,j)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're doing `del a[1]` you're not deleting the first element in dictionary, you're deleting the element with key 1. Dictionary does not have any ordering and thus slicing algorigthm (in this case at least).
That's why with the dict `a = {1 : 'one', 5 : 'five'}` you can do `del a[1]` and cannot do `del a[2]` or `del a[0]`